# C++ Have lone executable log exceptions?

Tags: c++, debugging, exception, logging

I'm currently in a beta testing phase of my C++ Server.
I'm sending it out to users to stress test it to see if an exceptions show up.

However, since the .exe is a standalone, how do I make it so it automatically creates a dump or a log of some sort if an exception happens?

My server has thousands of lines of code and uses two threads.
Would I just do a try and catch statement inside the two main thread calls and log the exception to a log file?

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Express C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, since the .exe is a standalone, how do I make it so it
>   automatically creates a dump or a log of some sort if an exception
>   happens?

If your program crash it will automatically creates a core dump and you can collect core dump and analyze it. But it will not create any log by itself. You should be created a logging module in your program and enable logging while you were coding the program.

> Would I just do a try and catch statement inside the two main thread
>   calls and log the exception to a log file?

You can do that, but you may get a minimal info from it, if program is very complicated. If you are planning to use exception you should create an exception hierarchy and should do it while coding.

Comment: I think I'll do the log system. Thank you!